# How can I put Customer Name in the vs-input using loop, then it should pass the customer id to form.co_id in VueJS

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

How can I put Customer Name in the vs-input using loop, then it should pass the customer id to form.co_id in VueJS? The looping part is done, I just can't figure out how can I output the customer name but it will pass customer id to form.co_id.

I have this code:

```
<div v-for="(customer, co_id) in filteredCustomers" :key="co_id" :value="customer.co_id">
         <vs-input type="text" v-bind:value="customer.co_name" v-on:input="form.co_id = $event.target.value"></vs-input>
</div>
```

and VueJS

```
data() {
    return {
       form: { co_id:'')
     }
 },
 computed: {
    filteredCustomers(){
        let filteredCustomers = [];
        for(let i = 0 ; i < this.customers.length ; i++) {
            let customers = this.customers[i];
            if(customers.co_id == this.form.device.customer_id) {
                filteredCustomers.push(customers);
            }
        }
        console.log(filteredCustomers);
        return filteredCustomers;
    },
```

Comment: Hello there, not sure if that helps but maybe it'll point you towards the right direction: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-cookies-rrx00?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Hi! What I intend to do is that whenever I choose a device name in my first select tag (list of devices), values will be automatically set (customer.co_name for the value then customer.co_id for the form.co_id)